Vue3: Ignore parts of template
I am migrating a large application from Vue2 to Vue3. On some pages, structured schema.org data in JSON-LD format is delivered from the server to the template. While Vue2 was not bothered by this (no JS code is executed), Vue3 now throws a warning:
[Vue warn]: Template compilation error: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates. <script type=“application/ld+json”>
How do I get rid of that warning?
I have already tried to hide the script tag in a <template>, or to ignore it with a v-pre, but the message still appears. Are there any other ways to tell Vue to ignore that part of the template?

This is full duplicate of the existing question. I posted an answer there instead

You could try this approach.
Apparently, it might also be an unclosed tag.
I did not find any way to disable the warnings but you could always filter the error in your browser's console.
Also, what happens if you omit the type="application/ld+json" part?

The <component is="script"> approach works and fixes the warning. Although IMHO it's not a good solution, because Vue uselessly compiles the whole tag. Ideally, this does not happen.

If I remove the type="application/ld+json" part from script, the Vue warning stays the same. The browser  throws an error, because the code inside is not valid JS.

@Reynicke I mean, there are no good solutions when it comes down to compiling the template from an external source with an already running app AFAIK. You could use Render Functions or maybe v-html but it might not be a compatible solution with your use-case or just not really better. Given your specific implementation and the fact that this is only a warning, I don't think that it's very bad to proceed this way. What would be a better solution from your perspective considering the fact that you do have a huge app to migrate. Maybe ask on Discord, some core people might maybe know further.

This is not just a warning to ignore, script tags are removed by the compiler. Besides the security concerns, v-html isn't supported in ssr. Render function would be the first choice then
